# QGIS : See ID in polygons in ascending order

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.10

I have input polygons in shp, I assign id with $rownum but to display a label with the order isn't good. It seems to bind to the entry order. 
[image]

How to automatically change the id for them in order to display?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: i think the only order you have is the entry order. To build a spatial order is not trivial and there is no build-in function in QGIS.
may be there is a tricky approach with some geoprocessing? Im thinking of line features crossing the polygons, 
then intersect and assign m-values along the lines by a kind of linear referencing. 
After that you may be able to spatially join the polygons to the vertex points. Just an idea, else, i fear, you have to edit the features manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the idea [Andreas Müller](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/46073/andreas-m%C3%BCller). I solved my problem with an order rather manual solution.

I created a point layer and I grabbed each point in polygon in the desired order. I put an ID to my points with $rownum. Then I made a join attribute by location (menu vector -> Data management tools) to assign the ID of the point to my polygon.

This solution avoids to modify the numbers manually in each polygon with risk of error and offset value